# Чтения хранилища на чужом сайте

Tags: база-данных, парсер, веб-сервер, веб-сайт, хранилище

Появился такой вопрос. Хочу сделать инструмент, который позволил бы видеть отзывы ваших товаров на wildberries. Зашел я значит через сафари в инструменты разработчика и смог отыскать нужное хранилище. Я вижу всю информацию в нем, как мне и надо, однако, ума не приложу как получить прямую ссылку на это хранилище, чтобы вставить ее в код, чтобы он так же мог читать озывы. Приклепряю скрин: [image: введите сюда описание изображения] Вот эту информацию, которая нахоидтся в свободном доступе и нужно спарсить. Вопрос лишь в том, как по тем данным, что мы видим, получить ссылку на это хранилище?? Заранее благодарю за помощь!!!

Comment: Похоже это то, что сайт локально сохраняет в вашем браузере, см. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB. Такая информация хранится в вашем профиле, но, возможно, она зашифрована - зависит от реализации в браузере и его настроек. Мб через selenium это получится вытащить или сделав расширение для браузера

Answer (score 0):

Данные берутся отсюда:
[https://feedbacks1.wb.ru/feedbacks/v1/{$rootId}](https://feedbacks1.wb.ru/feedbacks/v1/%7B$rootId%7D)
Либо отсюда:
[https://feedbacks2.wb.ru/feedbacks/v1/{$rootId}](https://feedbacks2.wb.ru/feedbacks/v1/%7B$rootId%7D)